# ¿Por qué no funciona esta sentencia en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy programando con el servidor `atspace.com` . He intentado crear una página para repartir rublos pero no puedo, me lanza error al lanzar la siguiente sentencia MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (`P85097925`);
```

Este es el error:

> Error
>   consulta SQL:
>
> INSERT INTO users VALUES (`P85097925`)
>   MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'P85097925' in 'field list'

Parece muy raro. Normalmente esta sentencia se lanzaba con normalidad. Pero hasta hace poco ha comenzado a dar fallo. ¿Debería decírselo a soporte o está mal escrito el código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Causa del error

El error en sí ocurre porque estás usando *backticks*  (comillas invertidas) para los valores. En MySQL los backticks sirven para nombrar tablas, columnas, etc, pero no valores, por eso **está interpretando que `P85097925` es una columna, no un valor**.

Según el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) cada vez que usas <kbd>**`**</kbd> el manejador interpreta que te refieres a una base de datos, tabla o columna:

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`):

---

> El carácter identificador es la comilla invertida (`):

Como nota adicional, los backticks son opcionales. Pero si tienes nombres de tablas o columnas que a su vez son palabras reservadas (práctica no recomendada), debes usar backticks cuando escribas esas nombres en las consultas, así precisamente MySQL los va a diferenciar de las palabras reservadas.

El [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) también dice que las comillas simples <kbd>**'**</kbd> o la comillas dobles <kbd>**"**</kbd> se usan para encerrar cadenas:

> enclosed within either single quote (') or double quote (") characters.

---

> encerradas entre comillas simples (') o comillas dobles (")

## Solución

Varias soluciones son posibles.

### Solución no óptima

Si hay una sola columna en tu tabla, o dos columnas una de las cuales es auto incremental, entonces tu consulta debería funcionar así:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('P85097925');
```

Simplemente, se han cambiado los backticks por comillas simples, por lo que hemos dicho antes.

De todos modos, es mejor escribir consultas explícitas, ayudan a entender mejor nuestro programa y a saber siempre con lo que estamos trabajado. Además, si ahora tu tabla `users` tiene solamente una o dos columnas, pero mañana se le agrega(n) otra(s) columna(s), esta consulta ya es inviable y vas a tener que recorrer por todo el programa donde usas consultas como esta para actualizar el código.

### Solución óptima

Escribir una consulta que nombre la columna de forma explícita y listo.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`laColumna`) VALUES ('P85097925');
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta

Comment: Ya me había dado cuenta. Marco está respuesta como aceptada ;)

Comment: Puedes visitar mi sitio ya finalizado en faucet-rotator.surge.sh

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que indicar el nombre de la columna antes de `values` ya que no publicas la estructura de la tabla te indico el ejemplo con nombre_columna:

```
INSERT INTO users (nombre_columna) VALUES ('P85097925');
```

Answer (score 1):

Es sql básico, el error te dice que no existe la columna 'Pxxxxxx'

La sintaxis correcta es

```
INSERT INTO tabla (columna1, columna2, columna3, ...) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3, ...);
```

Sería algo asi

```
INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES ('P85097925');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cuando defines `VALUES` en tu script  , debes definir el o los campos en los cuales se insertará el valor.**

Ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, City, Country, Phone)
VALUES ('Werenverlivitz', 'Smith', 'York', 'Spain', 1-01-993 2800)
```

en este caso no esta definiendo el campo en el cual se insertaría el valor:

```
INSERT INTO users (< campo >) VALUES (P85097925)
```