# Error en comando sqli en php

Tags: php, sql

Al ejecutar esta busqueda

```
$BQuery ="SELECT * FROM Requisitos WHERE Nombre = ".$TagUeroRequi ;
```

Me responde al ejecutarla.

```
Unknown column 'Idioma' in 'where clause'
```

La variable se carga correctamente con la palabra Idioma que es la que quiero buscar. El nombre del campo es tambien correcto, a proposito le puse el nombre **Nombre**.

No se cual es el error. Probe colocando Nombre = '".$TagUeroRequi."'"; y mismo error.

Comment: Haz un echo a la variable $Bquery y dinos que te muestra. También una descripción de tu tabla Requisitos sería de gran ayuda

Comment: Así debería funcionar: **`$BQuery ="SELECT * FROM Requisitos WHERE Nombre = '$TagUeroRequi'";`** para los valores alfanuméricos tienes que usar comillas simples: `'`, el mensaje de error hace pensar que estabas usando backticks  en lugar de comillas simples, y eso para ¿mysql?  es [un identificador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/326013/29967) de tabla, de columna, de base de datos... Por cierto, ni siquiera sabemos si estás usando MySQL, conviene que pongas en la pregunta la etiqueta del manejador de base de datos correspondiente.

Comment: Hola buen dia, use este formato y me funciono, muchas gracias..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

prueba así:

```
$BQuery="SELECT * FROM Requisitos WHERE Nombre=".$TagUeroRequi;
```

y controla si estan bien escritas las variables y la consulta, si te llega bien `$TagUeroRequi` entonces esta mal la consulta, haz esto

```
$BQuery="SELECT * FROM Requisitos WHERE Nombre=".$TagUeroRequi;
echo $BQuery;die();
```

a ver que te imprimine y pegalo en el phpmyadmin a ver que resultado te da..