# ¿Por qué no crea la tabla?

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin

Estoy realizando un plugin de Wordpress e intento crear la tabla en la base de datos a través de la función Activar de mi plugin.

Al activarse, debería crearse la tabla si no existe. Pero verifico en la base de datos y no se crea. A continuación el código:

```php
        function Activar(){
    
        global $wpdb;
    
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "encuestas"; 
    
        $sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
        'EncuestaId' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            'Nombre' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
            'ShortCode' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY('EncuestaId'));)";
    
         $wpdb->query($sql); 
    }
    
    
    function Desactivar(){
    
        flush_rewrite_rules();
     }
     
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'Activar' );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'Desactivar');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu instrucción SQL está mal escrita.

- En MySQL tienes que usar *backticks* <kbd>**`**</kbd> para identificar tablas/columnas, pero tú estás usando comillas simples <kbd>**'**</kbd>, que sirve para cadenas. La instrucción por tanto no interpreta tus columnas como un elemento nomitativo, sino como una simple cadena <sup>1</sup>.
- Tienes un paréntesis de más al final de la instrucción, después del `;`

Poniendo el código así debería funcionar:

```
$sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name 
       (
          `EncuestaId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `ShortCode` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY(`EncuestaId`)
        );";
```

---

1. Puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/326013/29967) para más detalles (aunque allí ocurre lo contrario de lo que a ti). La respuesta explica con más claridad el sentido del uso de comillas invertidas (backticks) y de comillas dobles o simples en MySQL.

Comment: Era lo que necesitaba. muy agradecido!