# Problemas CREATE TABLE en MySQL Server 5.7

Tags: mysql

He creado dos contenedores con Docker para poder subir una aplicación a un servidor de Ubuntu Server. Uno de los contenedores corresponde a la base de datos. Los datos de esa BD los tengo que introducir manualmente, entonces he entrado a la BD con **mysql -u root -p**

Me disponía a crear manualmente las tablas pero me da errores y no entiendo cual es el fallo de sintaxis. ¿Que puede ser? Os dejo por aquí abajo las sentencias y error:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE ap_trans (
    ->   index1 int NOT NULL,
    ->   id_origen int NOT NULL,
    ->   id_destino int NOT NULL,
    ->   read1 char(1) NOT NULL,
    ->   stack char(1) NOT NULL,
    ->   push varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY ('index1'),
    ->   KEY idstate1idx ('id_origen'),
    ->   KEY idstate2idx ('id_destino'),
    ->   CONSTRAINT idstate_1 FOREIGN KEY ('id_origen') REFERENCES estados ('id_state'),
    ->   CONSTRAINT idstate_2 FOREIGN KEY ('id_destino') REFERENCES estados ('id_state')
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''index'),
  KEY idstate1idx ('id_origen'),
  KEY idstate2idx ('id_destino'),
  C' at line 8
```

Me gustaria poder crear esa tabla

Comment: Prueba nuevamente, pero sin las comillas que están entre los paréntesis en primary key, los KEY, y FOREIGN key así como REFERENCES

Answer (score 2):

Es preciso comprender que en MySQL se usan las comillas invertidas o backticks <kbd>**`**</kbd> como identificadores (nombrar tablas, columnas, etc). Pero tú estás usando comillas simples <kbd>**'**</kbd>, las cuales se usan para valores. Eso es lo que está causando el error de sintaxis.

Así debería funcionar:

```
CREATE TABLE `ap_trans` (
    `index1` int NOT NULL,
    `id_origen` int NOT NULL,
    `id_destino` int NOT NULL,
    `read1` char(1) NOT NULL,
    `stack` char(1) NOT NULL,
    `push` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`index1`),
    KEY `idstate1idx` (`id_origen`),
    KEY `idstate2idx` (`id_destino`),
    CONSTRAINT `idstate_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_origen`) REFERENCES `estados` (`id_state`),
    CONSTRAINT `idstate_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_destino`) REFERENCES `estados` (`id_state`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

NÓTESE que hemos usado backticks en TODAS las identificaciones. Es una buena práctica. Por ejemplo, si alguna tabla o columna tuviese un nombre que es palabra reservada (y por algún motivo tiene que ser así), esto impedirá que el código falle. Sin comillas también funciona, pero no en el caso de palabras reservadas por eso siempre es mejor usar backticks siempre, como buena práctica.

Para más detalles puedes consultar la pregunta: [¿Por qué no funciona esta sentencia en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/326003/29967).

Puede que el uso de `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` dé error, porque ese juego de caracteres sólo se incorporó [a partir de la versión 8 de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-charsets.html), por tanto, si tu código corre en una versión anterior tendrás error, y debes cambiar `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` por `utf8mb4_general_ci` ([ver aquí para más detalles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63995271/5587982)).

Answer (score 0):

lo que pude averiguar es que el problemas no es mas que las comillas simples en los campos a los cuales se hacer referencia.

```
CONSTRAINT idstate_1 FOREIGN KEY ('id_origen') REFERENCES estados ('id_state'),
```

Deberia ser:

```
CONSTRAINT idstate_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_origen) REFERENCES estados (id_state),
```

Adicional a esto me encontré con un problema al definir el CHARSET, no se si tendrás este problema :

> Error 1273 (HY000) at line 25 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

De ser así tendrás que reemplazar el CHARSET con :

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

[fuente](https://tecadmin.net/resolved-unknown-collation-utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/)